# How to get name of very first tag of XML with php's SimpleXML?

Tags: php, xml

I am parsing XML strings using `simplexml_load_string()`, but I noticed that i don't get the name of the very first tag.

For example, I have these two xml strings:

```
$s = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ParentTypeABC>
    <chidren1>
        <children2>1000</children2>
    </chidren1>
</ParentTypeABC>
';

$t = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ParentTypeDEF>
    <chidren1>
        <children2>1000</children2>
    </chidren1>
</ParentTypeDEF>
';
```

NOTICE that they are nearly identical, the only difference being that one has the first node as `<ParentTypeABC>` and the other as `<ParentTypeDEF>`

then I just convert them to SimpleXML objects:

```
$o = simplexml_load_string($s);
$p = simplexml_load_string($t);
```

but then i have two equal objects, none of them having the "top" node's name appearing, either `ParentTypeABC` or `ParentTypeDEF` (I examine the objects using `print_r()`):

```
// with top node "ParentTypeABC"
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [chidren1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [children2] => 1000
        )

)
// with top node "ParentTypeDEF"
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [chidren1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [children2] => 1000
        )

)
```

So how I am supposed to know the top node's name? If I parse unknown XMLs and I need to know what's the top node name, what can I do?

Is there an option in `simplexml_load_string()` I could use?

I know there are MANY ways to parse XML's with PHP, but I'd like it to be as simple as posible, and to get a simple object or array I could navigate easily.

I made a simple example [here](http://www.tehplayground.com/#uhEWSQhXK) to fiddle with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SimpleXML has a `getName()` method.

```
echo $xml->getName();
```

This should return the name of the respective node, no matter if root or not.

http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getname.php

Comment: well it works! But I still wonder, why doesn't it show up when I print the object usint `print_r()` or `vardump()`? How else could I see the complete structure of the SimpleXML object?

Comment: @DiegoDD: That is because `print_r()` and `var_dump()` display only the information of the object - and which the programmers of those objects were offering. What you're probably looking for is `$xml->asXML('php://output');` which outputs the actual XML and that is what you want to look into.